# Force Hard Page Refresh on Internal Navigation Menu Items

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I’ve embedded a job board from Lever on my WordPress site using the following tool:

https://andreasmb.github.io/lever-jobs-embed/

The page on which it is embedded is here:

http://1pd.aab.myftpupload.com/careers-test-3/

If you visit the link directly, it loads fine. However if you navigate to any other page on the site, then access it via the main navigation bar (Careers > Careers Test 3) the content does not load. You must refresh the page in order to see the content.

This is the embed code:

window.leverJobsOptions = {accountName: ‘geltor’, includeCss: true};https://andreasmb.github.io/lever-jobs-embed/index.js

Any help identifying the conflict and diagnosing the issue would be much appreciated. I’ve tried disabling all my plugins but to no avail.

As a quick fix, is there a way to force a hard refresh when any nav link is clicked?

Thank you!

disabled all plugins, to no avail. except the core theme plugins which are needed to run the site.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, did you try this?

```
document.location.reload(true)
```

Comment: Thanks Niklas. Where would I place that code, exactly?

Comment: One way is to just hard code an eventlistener for every nav item, a better way is to give them all a class, i e "reloadOnClick", loop through them and attach an eventlistener for every element.

Comment: Makes sense, I just can't figure out what file(s) I need to access in the WP theme to place that code. Theme files here: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/52mjkupp4d6xu66/themeforest-10949314-arno-multiconcept-theme-wordpress-theme.zip?dl=0

http://1pd.aab.myftpupload.com

Thanks Niklas!

Comment: Personally I would avoid editing PHP files directly, instead use a plugin or if built-in the theme, custom js & CSS in wp's web interface.

Comment: I do have the ability to inject custom code in the wp interface, but I am a novice when it comes to js and need help figuring out how to target those individual menu items with any sort of js code injection. I realize that would depend on the theme, which is why I included the URL and files...in case anyone is able to quickly point me in the right direction. Or if there is a particular plugin that would facilitate it, even better. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so I injected the following script directly into the body of the page on which I am trying to force a one-time reload.

<script>
document.location.reload(true);
</script>

It does not seem to refresh the page. However when I use this code (replacing "document" with "window") the page does refresh, but on an infinite loop. 

<script>
window.location.reload(true);
</script>